# how make document library custom upload form in office 365/Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, office-365, office, office-365-developer

I am working on office 365 and  want to make a custom upload form for document library to upload the document and also want to add two custom field on this form to save along with document upload.
  Is It possible using sharepoint designer and infopath ?
Please provide the solution ASAP, THANKS IN ADVANCE.

Comment: judging by the number of downvotes, you should probably try to spend a bit more time describing your scenario and what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can do this is by creating an Auto Hosted / Provider Hosted App or sand-boxed solution which will contain a custom upload form.

You will need to override the default upload form URL with the new URL where your custom form resides using JQuery

Answer (score 0):

You can create content types and associate these site content types with the document library either through PowerShell/manually.  After creating site content types, you can add the custom site columns you have created. These site columns are added to your document library and it will get saved along with the document after uploading the document.